# PhotoChooserTask.Completed not fired

Tags: windows-phone-7, photo

I'm trying to using `PhotoChooserTask` for our purposes. 
After calling `photoChooserTask.Show()` chooser is showed but when I choose a picture it's closing and event Completed **not fired** !

Why?

And more, after that `PhotoChooserTask` not showed next time when calling `Show`.

P.S. if i try this code in new solution - it will work fine, but why it doesn't work in our project?

```
PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask;
        private void button2_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
            photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
            photoChooserTask.Show();
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
        }

        void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            //Bla bla bla
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any code in the OnNavigatedTo of the same page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

So, project CAN NOT have more than one photo chooser. 
You can't declare `PhotoChooserTask` in Page1 and Page2 with different logic of processing.

Hope this will helpfull for someone.

Comment: I dont think so,I have 3 or 4 PhotoChooserTask 9 in my project,And the  problem occurs if two PhotoChooserTask  events fire at same time.

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure that you respect the guidelines for creating and initializing the object:

> To ensure that your application receives the result of the
>   PhotoChooserTask, the object must be declared with class scope
>   within the PhoneApplicationPage class and you must call the chooser
>   constructor and assign the Completed event delegate within the page’s
>   constructor.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask.photochoosertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)